# Creating update method in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I want to create a method for the update in a particular field of my record.
I'm new with Web API 2 in ASP.Net. I created a method but always get's an error

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

I want to create a custom method like this:

```
        [HttpPut]
        public string AddDeviceID(string deviceID)
        {

            User user = db.Users.Single(x => x.MobileUserName == "Dev" && x.MobilePassword == "123");
            user.MobileDeviceId = deviceID;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return "success";

        }
```

Here is my route config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{deviceId}",
            defaults: new { deviceId = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I don't know what am i missing on this code I'm just following the concept of ASP.Net MVC of creating a method for update.

Anybody could provide some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because yo are doing a GET when you should be send a PUT request with the data to the api.

Comment: How you tried to call `AddDeviceID()` action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happened because you executed HTTP GET request but your action is decorated with `[HttpPut]` attribute and can accept only HTTP PUT. To fix this you can implement functionality to execute HTTP PUT request or you can decorate your action with `[HttpGet]` attribute like in the following example:

```
[HttpGet]        
public string AddDeviceID(string deviceID)
{
        User user = db.Users.Single(x => x.MobileUserName == "Dev" && x.MobilePassword == "123");
        user.MobileDeviceId = deviceID;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return "success";
}
```

How you made the request? Please note that browser will makes HTTP GET request.

Comment: thank you very much it works!. But had some confusion with this. I'd use [HttpGet] because it will update record, I thought if we update record we use [HttpPut]. And also does it matter on the route config?

Comment: I mean I'd use [HttpPut] because it will update record..I'm confused.

Comment: @nyapz In general you have to use PUT for that kind of operation but you cannot call from browser. How you calling `AddDeviceID()` action?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your api with a HTTP PUT Request. You get this error, because you do a HTTP GET Request.

Even if you accepted the other answer, you realy should use the `HttpPut` Attribute, because it is more correct in the meaning.

[From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods):

> **GET**
>
> The GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. **Requests using GET should only retrieve data and should have
>   no other effect.** (This is also true of some other HTTP methods.)[1]
>   The W3C has published guidance principles on this distinction, saying,
>   "Web application design should be informed by the above principles,
>   but also by the relevant limitations."
>
> **PUT**
>
> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied URI. If the URI refers to an already existing resource,
>   it is modified; if the URI does not point to an existing resource,
>   then the server can create the resource with that URI.

Just google about how to send a `HTTP PUT Request` with the library/software you are testing.

By the way: [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is a good tool for testing.